# fullcalender v5 resource set icons

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using fullcalendar 5. The only problem that I have is that my icons wont display because it's using plain text.

I found the resourceLabelDidMount option to add a html element. However that applies to the parent and child and not to the child only.

```
resourceLabelDidMount: function(data) {
  var icon = document.createElement('strong');
  icon .innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>';


  data.el.querySelector('.fc-datagrid-cell-main') .appendChild(icon );
},
```

[image: example]

Is there a way to use a icon for the second and third child column?